# Merged into a branch and lost the commit in the next push

Tags: git, git-merge

Morning SO,

My problem is the following:

There was a master commit and push that I had to revert, I asked the user then to create a branch for his commit so I could merge it with a pull request, everything went fine, merged into my master and deleted the branch.

I also had to merge this master into develop so the two would be aligned, in doing that I could see that the previous merge "disappeared" file-wise into my master and if now I clone the repository it won't show the files that I merged with that pull request.

Running a git log I get the following:

```
* f9f9137 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/layout, origin/develop, develop) Version 3.1.73
*   f81b163 Merge branch 'master' into develop
|\  
| *   6c73f7b Merge branch 'feature/TimesheetReminder' into 'master'
| |\  
* | | 1a05d2f Revert "Timesheet reminder version 1"
| |/  
|/|   
* | 83d082a Timesheet reminder version 3
* | d22ed67 Timesheet reminder version 1
* |   4e71765 Merge branch 'feature/checkboxes' into 'develop'
|\ \  
| |/  
|/|   
| * 98c090b bugs fixed
| * bb3238c open tabs corrected
| * 4e5feb4 checkboxes + buttons added to homepage
|/  
* cf357ee Edited browser icon
* 84a9050 Version 3.1.72
* 5adf3c0 Modified resources and added logo with the GhostForce name
* ec2a99a Version 3.1.71
* 14b8626 Modified assets and changed KB link.
```

`d22ed67` and `83d082a` were the 2 wrong commits, I reverted to  `d22ed67` since it had just one small addition that was fine to keep, then the user created a new branch and submitted the pull request: `6c73f7b` and I proceeded to merge that into my master, then I ran a `git checkout develop && git merge master`.

Now if I go into the master I do not see the additions from `1a05d2f` but if I browse the repository with that id I do see all the correct files being added.

What could be the issue here, what did I do wrong?

Comment: `6c73f7b` seems to literally only be a merge from the master (without your revert). Why does this branch exist at all and why bother merging it? I would of just deleted the branch and started again if needed, or rebased it to the correct point in the graph

Comment: Hey Liam, thanks for the quick reply.
`6c73f7b` was created to integrate the changes of  `83d082a` with a merge request instead of being pushed directly into master (since I wanted to test it before merging it), was this a wrong approach? I am still fairly new to git.

Comment: But that's not what your graph shows. `83d082a` is in master? Did you merge your branch into master? `6c73f7b` seems to be a strange merge of you change and a previous commit. I still maintain `6c73f7b` is pointless an contains literally no information and your "missing commit" doesn't appear to be missing.

Comment: Ok, I think the quickest way to resolve all this is to `reset` master to `1a05d2f` `force push` this and delete `feature/TimesheetReminder` cos it's not doing anything at all.

Comment: If you have upstream changes that aren't shown this this gets a lot more messy

Comment: Hey @Liam yes, `83d082a` that was a commit/push directly into the master upstream so it was not done via branch and merge that is why I reverted and asked the user to create a branch for this feature. My "missing" commit is there, absolutely, that is why I am confused, because when I clone the repo, the changes from `6c73f7b` are not inside my folders. I have everything correct in my git log, the problem is that this additions do not show in my local freshly cloned repository or with a `git fetch` or `git pull` . Sorry if I explained myself the wrong way

Comment: `6c73f7b` doesn't contain any changes, at all? So your not missing anything. This is just a merge commit.

Comment: `6c73f7b` contains `83d082a` since I reverted it and asked the user to create a branch instead of pushing his changes into the master directly.

Comment: This is an [image](https://i.imgur.com/QvU5OWt.png) of that merge but I do not see this changes in my `master` if I clone it. There is no `dateCheck.js` for example.

Comment: Ok, look at the lines going to `6c73f7b` the only thing going into this merge is your master branch twice. If this had changes in it, I'd expect to see another `*`. Unless you've rendered your ANSI diagram incorrectly, that commit contains no code. I presume this isn't a public repo? I think what your seeing is just code from an older version, GIT knows it's old (and is already in the master branch) so it's not applying it, it's already there! Now you might of overwritten this change, but GIT knows the commit is already merged

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for your clarification on this regards, it is still a bit confusing the way git handles this situations for me but hopefully this will come with time. Do you suggest to just revert the `master` to  `83d082a` and keep it that way? If so please post this as answer so I can accept that.

Comment: If that's what you want to do then, yes. I'm not 100% clear what your end game is here. But it seems you just want to get the branch back to a point in time, I typically use `git reset --hard` -> `git push -f` (use with caution this will essentially delete commits)

Comment: Excuse me I am not English native so my communication can be wacky sometimes. My end game would be having in the `master` the files (ex. `dateCheck.js` that was an addition) that you can see in the above posted image because I do not currently see them in my repository.

Comment: Well that depends on a whole lot of `if`s. If I were you cut and paste it into your repo and commit. Job done. You can do it "more GIT" but I don't have anywhere near enough information to guide you in that and from what your saying your not clear on the subtleties of GIT. Cut and paste is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned *`d22ed67 and 83d082a were the 2 wrong commits`*

As you have very few commits above these commits, the better way (if the issue happens to me I would prefer this!)

```
git log --oneline -20 
git reset --hard 4e71765
git cherry-pick 1a05d2f
git cherry-pick 6c73f7b
git cherry-pick f81b163
git cherry-pick f9f9137
git log --oneline -20
```

`git log` is required as you might miss any commit ID, you can get it from there and to avoid confusion. Also do each cherry-picks one by one.

Also, if you get any conflicts while cherry-pick -

- Resolve the conflicts (there are may ways to resolve conflicts)
- then add the changed files (even if it is added already)
- do a commit
- then put `git cherry-pick --continue`
- After that keep cherry-picking all other commits.

**Note** : 
1. Please **do not** use `merge` command. Use `rebase`
2. Please **do not** use `pull` command. Use `fetch` and then `rebase`

Happy gitification !!

Comment: Regarding your last comment: While I would agree that `rebase` should typically be preferred over `merge` for local work, I don't think it is a good idea to avoid `merge` entirely.  `merge` and `rebase` are different tools and each have different uses.

Comment: *do not use merge* what is this advice based on? what about when you need a merge? There is no blanket, use rebase not merge, that's just silly. *Please do not use pull command* really? How do you pull?

Comment: @Liam - Please see my explanation too :) how to do merge / pull without using those keywords. @ 0x5453 it's my experience. When I had issues because of using merge & pull I researched and found it's better not to use those. After that (for the past 3 to 4 years) I am not using merge / pull even I use git daily !!!